# Attempting to trouble shoot email issues but I have no exp_postmaster_mailbox

Tags: php, email, database, mailing

I currently have two sites I'm working on right now which utilize the built in email module. I can fill the form out, hit submit and I get a message saying it's been sent, but it never gets sent. I can also use the communicate field, and again, nothing gets sent although I get confirmation that it did indeed send.

While trouble shooting I've come across the suggestion that I check the database table called "exp_postmaster_mailbox" and I wonder if I may have found my issue - there is no "exp_postmaster_mailbox" in my database.

Is this a corrupt install? It doesn't work live or local. It also doesn't matter whether I use phpmail, sendgrid, or smtp. None send all, all give confirmation that it sent out.

Comment: Just FYI, I have got your email. I am working Postmaster bug fixes now and will be getting back to you shortly.

Comment: Hey @JustinKimbrell I'm not sure you're talking to the same person but I'd love to know what sort of solution or problem you're working on. Can you post back here or do you want my email?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I got a similar email around the same time and thought it was the same person. Sometimes people send and email and post publicly to see if somebody else can answer faster. Send me an email and we will get this figured out and then post back here. support@objectivehtml.com

Answer (score 1):

Just figured I would update this thread for others since I commented. This turns out to be a misunderstanding on my part thinking he was using Postmater since the question has a Postmaster table in the subject and throughout the post. Turns out, reading more carefully reveals he is *not* using Postmaster and just the native email module.

Postmaster would be a perfect candidate as an alternative solution to solving this problem, but it's doesn't exactly solve *this* problem in the direct sense.

And to clarify further, the exp_postmaster_mailbox table is a component of the Postmaster add-on by Objective HTML. So this table would not be found in a default EE install.

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster